# Can a context consumer retrieve history values for an entity through Orion?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I am new with Fiware technologies and I have read many documents regarding Orion Context Broker but is not clear for me if a context consumer can request from Orion Context Broker history values about an entity.

I mean that if the context consumer need the measurements from day 1 to day 10 from a single temperature sensor to make an analysis, can it request those values from Orion or the context consumer can only retrieved those values from the database that are stored?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s13z.png)

Does Orion has this capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context base managed by Orion Context Broker corresponds to the *current* status of the system. In other words, if a given attribute of a given entity has a value and a new update changes that value, then the old one is overriden.

This is not a limitation of Orion, but a design principle, due to the responsability of storing *historical context* is on charge of other FIWARE components. In particular, [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus) is used to persist such historical information. It plays the role of a context consumer, subscribing to Orion and storing data in several persistence backends (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL, MongoDB, etc.). It can be used in combination with [Short Term Historic](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet), that provides a REST API similar to Orion NGSIv1 API in order to get raw historical data and some basic aggregations (sum, average, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand that at any given time Orion keeps the most updated value of an entity, my question is if a context consumer can request through Orion history values for that entity instead of communicate directly with the database that those values are stored. I will include an image with an example of what I mean for better understanding.

Comment: No, is not working that way. You application would need to access the persistance backend (MySQL in the case of your picture) in order to get the history values.